# Hide a select box itself if there is only 1 option available

Tags: javascript

How do I hide a select box if there is only 1 option available. (it is a dynamic select box that gets updated by another select box)

Comment: Do you mean how can you detect the condition of 'there is now only 1 option', or how to actually prevent it from displaying?

Comment: Could you please paste your code, so someone can help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($('#select_list>option').length == 1)
  $('#select_list').hide();
```

Comment: It fascinates me that the OP never mentioned or tagged jQuery anywhere in his question and this is what you post, without any explanation as to what it is or how it works. Even more fascinating is that it was selected as the answer...

Answer (score 0):

put this at the end of the code that updates the options in the drop down (`selectid` should be the id of your `select` element):

```
if ($('select#selectid option').length == 1)
    $('select#selectid option').hide();
else
    $('select#selectid option').show();
```

Comment: When you mean 'select', what am I supposed to put?

Comment: the `select` before the `#` refers to the element type, `selectid` after the `#` refers to the element name, so if your dropdown has the id `myDropDown` then you would use `$('select#myDropDown option')`

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectBox  = document.getElementById("selectBox");
if(selectBox.length == 1)
{
    selectBox.style.cssText = "display:none";
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but it works only after I change to another option

Comment: Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.

Comment: Put this in a function that runs using the onLoad attribute of the first select box. So when that box loads this function will run.